# How can I prove that $P \neq EXP$

Tags: computational-complexity

It seems like $P\neq EXP$ is much easier than $P \neq NP$. How can I prove $P \neq EXP$?

(Well, after all I want to know any proof technique of proving there does not exist any algorithm of certain time complexity to prove a decision problem.)

It seems like we have to construct a problem where there's no way but to check all the cases which is exponential time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess [this is what you are looking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem#Deterministic_time_hierarchy_theorem) for.